# How may I place konsole tabs on the left side?

Tags: tabs, konsole

Is it possible to place the konsole tabs on the left (or right) side, instead of at the top or at the bottom?  Seems can't be done by using a user-defined stylesheet.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would like to do this too.  When you have lots of tabs open, it's hard to see which is which.  A list down the side would allow the tabs to be displayed fully.